# Mercurial hg clone from one server to another

Tags: mercurial

So I have my mercurial repo on one server, and that repo has our backup configuration files that we need for if our other main server decides to severely crash on us. Now, how would one clone the repo from the first server into the other server using Http or Https? I thought `hg clone https://user@server//home/repo` would work, but it didn't. Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting a hook on the main server to automatically push changes to the backup server.  Something like this:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.backup = hg push http://backupserver/repo
```

As mentioned in @dkson's answer that still requires that you be running a server on the the backup server, but it will make all pushes to the main server automatically mirrored.

If the backup server is accessible via ssh you can do:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.backup = hg push ssh://user@backupserver//absolute/path/to/repo
```

which **does not** require that `hg serve` or similar be running on the backup server.